# shell script: search and replace over multiple lines

Tags: regex, linux, unix, replace

I'm looking for a way to search and replace over multiple lines through a shell script. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
source:
[stuff before]
<!--WIERD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_BEGIN-->
  [stuff here, possibly multiple lines.
<!--WIERD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_END-->
[stuff after]    

target:
[stuff before]
[new content]
[stuff after]
```

In short, I want to delete the comments and everything between them and replace with some new content. Basically, I want to do a simple sed command over multiple lines, and if possible just using some basic *nix tools, no additional scripting language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to match complete lines then you can do this task with
`awk`.  Something like:

```
    awk -v NEWTEXT=foo 'BEGIN{n=0} /COMMENT_BEGIN/ {n=1} {if (n==0) {print $0}} /COMMENT_END/ {print NEWTEXT; n=0}' < myfile.txt
```

If the file is not so well formatted, with comments on
the same line as text you want to keep or remove, then I
would use `perl`, read the entire file into a single string,
do a regular expression match and replace on that string, then write the new string to
a new file.  This is not so simple and you need to write a `perl` script to do the work.
Something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$newtext = "foo\nbar";
$/ = '';  # no input separator so whole file is read.
$s = <>;  # read whole file from stdin
$startPattern = quotemeta('<!--WIERD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_BEGIN-->');
$endPattern = quotemeta('<!--WIERD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_END-->');
$pattern = $startPattern . '.+' . $endPattern;
$s =~ s/$pattern/$newtext/sg;
print $s;
```

Comment: my file is pretty straight forward so that should do the trick. out of curiosity, is there any basic unix tool that can do it for me if I couldn't go by lines, or do I need something more powerful?

Comment: I think this is too difficult for `sed` or other basic UNIX tools.  I added an example in `perl` - I think this is the simplest possible solution when not working line-by-line.

Answer (score 1):

`sed` does this just fine. The following is as simple as it gets; if you need to extract stuff from the delimiter line before the start delimiter or after the end delimiter, that's going to be a little more complex.

```
sed '/<!--WIERD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_BEGIN-->/,/<!--WIERD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_END-->/d' input >output
```

If you have any control over this, fix the spelling of "weird".

Answer (score 1):

another solution... this is possible to be done in a one-liner, but using **perl** regular expressions, which I find easier to work with than *sed* or *awk* (which are cumbersome with multi-line match and replace):

```
perl -0 -i -pe 's/<!--WIERD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_BEGIN-->[\s\S]*<!--WIERD_SPECIAL_COMMENT_END-->/your new content here/gim' yourfile1.txt
```

please note that this will replace the file with the new, changed content.